# can't use input while handling keyboardInterrupt, UnicodeDecodeError, but goes well outside handle keyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode, keyboardinterrupt

I write a spider and save those alreadly caught data in a list, I want to save data when I press the ctrl+c, but I find it that while handling the KeyboardInterrupt, UnicodeDecodeError happens in "save_flag = input('If continue program enter "y", save and exit enter "n": ')",
the traceback is at below,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyProject\win32\fileshutil.py", line 10, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyProject\win32\fileshutil.py", line 13, in <module>
    save_flag = input('If continue program enter "y", save and exit enter "n": ')
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

---

```
import sys
import time

try:
    while True:
        print('1')
        """
        some code
        """
        time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    save_flag = input('If continue program enter "y", save and exit enter "n": ')
    if save_flag == 'y':
        """
        save code
        """
        sys.exit()
    elif save_flag == 'n':
        sys.exit()
```

I find it that the text in the input is print correctly, and I do not know why is happens. I try to def the code in handle KeyboardInterrput in a function like below,

```
def handle_keyboard_interrupt():
    save_flag = input('If continue program enter "y", save and exit enter "n": ')
    if save_flag == 'y':
        """
        save code
        """
        sys.exit()
    elif save_flag == 'n':
        sys.exit()
```

but same UnicodeDecodeError happens. and I tried use

```
'If continue program enter "y", save and exit enter "n": '.encode(encoding="utg-8")
```

to force encoding with utf-8, but same error.